# How to run a bat file from Python 3.3.2

Tags: python, batch-file

I am developing a program in python, however I have a little problem because the data that my program needs, it is from the result of a bat file, so I would like to create something that I help me to run just my script in python and not use the bat file directly.

Well, right now, I have to execute the following steps:

1. I create a txt file where I enter the input data (For example: A.txt)
2. I run the BAT file using the file A.txt
3. It creates a new file txt which has the result of running the BAT file (For example: B.txt)
4. I open the file B.txt and I copy all data and then I paste it in a new txt file, where it will serve as input data to my program in python
5. I run my program in python
6. it creates a new file txt where has the final results
7. End

How can I improve this, I mean, Which scripts I need to run my program in Python without to go to the  Bat file and to do the steps that I describe above?

Comment: The first question is - what does the bat file do?

Comment: Why do you copy all the data in B.txt into a new txt file?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid The BAT file calculates velocities

Comment: The easiest way to solve this problem is to calculate your velocities in Python.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid yes... maybe it is a good idea but the problem is that I don't know how to migrate from Bat to Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure whatever you're doing in the `bat` file you can doit in a python module. So:

**Write a python module sustitute for your *.bat**

Write a python module containing a function for read the file `A.txt` and return the results. Then use that module from your program.

For instance:

```
# calculations.py, the bat substitute.

def calculate_from_input(file_name):
    input_ = open(file_name, 'rb') # The mode you read the fike depends on your purposes.
    # .... Do your calculations
    return result   # Return a list of velocities, for example.
```

Then in your main program

```
from calculations import calculate_from_input

calculated_data = calculate_from_input("A.txt")  # Then, you have the data ready to use in your program.
```

Comment: Well, I will try to sustitute the BAT file to python file, I don't know how to do it because I do not know to program in .BAT... well anyway thanks for your idea!